# p:remoteCommand not working in async mode

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would appreciate if somebody could give me a help here.

I am having a tabbed layout on a page where by clicking on a tab (p:commandLink) I would like to initialize appropriate data for that tab and update the region displaying the content. As I want the initialization to happen lazily (when tab content is rendered), I am using Primefaces's p:remoteCommand.

The problem is that when I set the p:remoteCommand to work asynchronously (async=true), this functionality is not working, the action method is not called. When attribute 'async' is false, it works.

Example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:form id="peopleForm">
        <h:panelGroup id="panel1">
            #{testbean.message}
        </h:panelGroup>

        <p:remoteCommand name="lazyInit"
            onstart="console.log('calling init')"
            action="#{testbean.init()}" 
            update=":peopleForm:panel1"
            async="true"
         />

        <script>
        $(function(){
            console.log('before call');
            lazyInit();
            console.log('after call');
        });
        </script>
    </h:form>

    <p:commandLink update=":peopleForm" value="Tab1" action="#{testbean.setMenuSelected('Tab1')}"/>

    <p:commandLink update=":peopleForm" value="Tab2" action="#{testbean.setMenuSelected('Tab2')}"/>
</f:view>
</html>

@ManagedBean(name = "testbean")
@Component("testbean")
@Scope("session")
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2760060999550263904L;

    private String message;
    private String menuSelected = "Tab1";

    public void init() {
        if (menuSelected.equals("Tab1")) {
            message = "Tab1";
        }
        if (menuSelected.equals("Tab2")) {
            message = "Tab2";
        }
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public String getMenuSelected() {
        return menuSelected;
    }

    public void setMenuSelected(String menuSelected) {
        this.menuSelected = menuSelected;
    }
}
```

When async="true", it doesn't work, testbean.init() method is not called on link click. When 'async' is false, it works.

I am not sure whether 'async' is intended for this type of use case, or I misunderstood it.

Background:
In my application, I actually have multiple regions I want to update on tab change. And each region has its own initialization method that pulls the appropriate data from the database. The reason I want to have async calling of these initialization methods is that I do not want other initialization methods to wait for the first one to complete, and then the second one to complete etc. All those methods are mutually independent, so there is no reason for the synchronization between them. Ultimately, this should speed up displaying the page content to the user.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and worked it around by replacing `p:remoteCommand` with a hidden `p:commandLink`. Then there is no `name` attribute, so you need to use JavaScript to click the link.

```
(...)

<h:head>
    <script>
        function lazyInitClick() {
            $("[id$='lazyInit']").click();
        }
    </script>
</h:head>

(...)

<h:form>
    <p:commandLink id="lazyInit" actionListener="#{testbean.init()}" async="true" style="display: none;" />
    <h:outputScript>lazyInitClick()</h:outputScript>
</h:form>

(...)
```